# Error on update:org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: failed to execute script

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, updates, scala-2.11

i have a following document {

```
 "_index" : "Testdb",
  "_type" : "directUser",
  "_id" : "123",
  "_version" : 8,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"uuid":"123",
"Email":"mail@example.com"
,"SecondryEmail":"mail2@example.com"
,"FirstName":"personFirstNmae"
,"LastName":"personLastName"
,"UserStatus":"INACTIVE"
,"Password":"pwd"
}}
```

i want to update the `LastName` field's value 
here is my code

```
var lastname="lname"

var params:java.util.Map[String,Object] = Maps.newHashMap();
params.put("lastname", value);


val response = client.prepareUpdate("testdb", "directUser", directUserObj.getUuid)
.setScript("ctx._source.LastName = lastname",ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
.setScriptParams(params)
.execute().actionGet();
```

but this code throws following exception

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: failed to execute script
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:202)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:176)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:170)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.instance.TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction$1.run(TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction.java:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptException: scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.compile(ScriptService.java:285)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.executable(ScriptService.java:457)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:196)
    ... 6 more
```

please gudie me what am i going wrong i am using elasticsearch version 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the relevant error message:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptException: scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled
```

which means you need to add this:

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on
```

to `elasticsearch.yml` file and restart the nodes.